# EF Core 6 Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have the following tables in my DbContext:

```
    public class Employee 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public UserRole Role { get; set; }
        public string? Salutation { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get;set; }
        public string? MiddleName { get;set; }
        public string? LastName { get;set; }
        public string? DisplayName { get; set; }  
        public virtual Address? Address { get; set; }
        public byte[]? Image { get; set; } = null;
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
        public virtual Institution? Institution { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Permission>? Permissions { get; set; }        
        public virtual List<EmploymentLog> EmploymentLogs { get; set; }
        public bool HasAllPermission()
        {
            return HasPermission(Tasks.All);
        }

        public bool HasPermission(Tasks task)
        {
            //If no permissions were granted, return false
            if (Permissions == null) return false;

            //Check if user has all permission
            if (Permissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Task == Tasks.All && p.Access) != null) return true;

            //Check for the specific permisson           
            var permission = Permissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Task == task);
            return permission != null && permission.Access;
        }

   public bool HasPermissionSuper(Tasks task)
        {
            //If no permissions were granted, return false
            if (Permissions == null) return false;

            //Check if user has all permission
            if (Permissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Task == Tasks.Super && p.Access) != null) return true;

            //Check for the specific permisson           
            var permission = Permissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Task == task);
            return permission != null && permission.Access;
        }
    }
    public class EmploymentLog
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public EmploymentEventType EventType { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee InitiatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime InitiatedOn { get; set; }
        public EmploymentEventStatus Status { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee ApprovedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime ApprovedOn { get; set; }
    }

    //Model Builder:
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmploymentLog>()
              .HasOne(e => e.Employee)
              .WithMany(e => e.EmploymentLogs)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

The employee table holds records of all the employees, the EmploymentLogs table holds records of changes in the employment records of the employees, for example when an employees joins the company for the first time, a record in generated in the EmploymentLogs table, or when an employee is promoted, demoted, suspended or terminated a record is generated in the EmploymentLogs table, while updating the database I'm having the following error:

Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'EmploymentLog.ApprovedBy' of type 'Employee'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I have previously worked with EF6 and such code would've run nicely, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's because you have two Employee-typed properties, and EF can't decide which one is the inverse of Employee.EmployeeLogs (as a human, you know it's Employee, but EF can't know that) - see HasForeignKey in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key - and tell it about both relationships. it comes up a lot; just google "Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation"

Comment: ef seems to be confused as you have two relation to `Employee`, the `public virtual Employee Employee` and the `public virtual Employee ApprovedBy`. have you tried to be verbose and define the foreign key for `ApprovedBy`?

Answer (score 7):

> I have previously worked with EF6 and such code would've run nicely, what I'm doing wrong?

Forget about EF6. Even though there are some similarities, EF Core is completely different system with it's own conventions and rules that you need to follow.

The error message indicates that EF Core cannot *automatically* determine some relationship(s). This usually happens when you have more than one navigation property to another entity, and in your case, the `EmploymentLog` has 3 reference navigations to `Employee` - `Employee`, `InitiatedBy` and `ApprovedBy`, and the other entity `Employeee` has single collection navigation property to `EmploymentLog` - `EmploymentLogs`.

Hence what you need is at minimum to map explicitly the associated relationships (navigation property pairs, foreign key, cascade delete behavior etc.). You already did for the one of them, now do the same for the other two, e.g.

```cs
// EmploymentLog relationships

// Employee (many-to-one)
modelBuilder.Entity<EmploymentLog>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Employee) // reference
    .WithMany(e => e.EmploymentLogs) // collection
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

// InitiatedBy (many-to-one)
modelBuilder.Entity<EmploymentLog>()
    .HasOne(e => e.InitiatedBy) // reference
    .WithMany() // no collection
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

// ApprovedBy (many-to-one)
modelBuilder.Entity<EmploymentLog>()
    .HasOne(e => e.ApprovedBy) // reference
    .WithMany() // no collection
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```